# Php - creating json object

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create a json object from the data that I get from [Ninja Forms](http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/fields/) that would look like this:

```
{
    "title": "Contact Me",
    "fields": [
        { 
            "label": "Name",
            "type": "textbox",
            "required": "1"
        },
        { 
            "label": "Email",
            "type": "email",
            "required": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to do so, like this:

```
$settings = ['label', 'type', 'required'];
$formTitle = Ninja_Forms()->form( 1 )->get()->get_setting('title');
$formFields = Ninja_Forms()->form(1)->get_fields();
$data = ['title' => $formTitle];

foreach ($formFields as $formField) {
    $key = $formField->get_setting('key');

    foreach ($settings as $setting) {
        $data['fields'][$key][][$setting] = $formField->get_setting($setting);
    }
}

return $data;
```

But, the result of that looks like this:

```
{
    "title": "Contact Me",
    "fields": {
        "name": [
            { "label": "Name" },
            { "type": "textbox" },
            { "required": "1"}
        ],
        "email": [
            { "label": "Email" },
            { "type": "email" },
            { "required": "1" }
        ],
```

How can I do this, so that the result looks like the one I have shown above?
I have also tried like this:

```
  foreach ($settings as $setting) {
     $data['fields'][] = $formField->get_setting($setting);
  }
```

But, that gave me this kind of result:

```
{
    "title": "Contact Me",
    "fields": [
        "Name",
        "textbox",
        "1",
        "Email",
        "email",
        "1",
        "Message",
        "textarea",
        "1",
        "Submit",
        "submit",
        null
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This gave me the wanted result:

```
foreach ($formFields as $formField) {
  $key = $formField->get_setting('key');

  foreach ($settings as $setting) {
    $object[$setting]  = $formField->get_setting($setting);
  }
  $data['fields'][] = $object;
}

return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is to count the dimensions of the data. In your desired format, the deepest item is:

```
{ "fields": [ { "label": "Name"
```

So you have `object -> array -> object`.

If we indent each array in your code, we have:

```
$data // outermost array
  ['fields']
    [$key]
       [] // innermost array
          [$setting] = $value; // key in innermost array
```

Or if we were to declare it with just one value:

```
$data = array(
  'field' => array(
     $key => array(
        0 => array(
           $setting => $value
        )
     )
   )
);
```

So you have 4 levels of array, instead of 3.

Comparing to the JSON, taking an array with numeric keys as "array" and one with non-numeric keys as "object", the pattern is `object -> object -> array -> object`.

So it's the `[$key]` we need to eliminate, because it's creating an extra `object` dimension.

*But* we don't want to increment the key at `[]` for each item either, so we need to either make our value in advance...

```
foreach ($settings as $setting) {
  $object[$setting]  = $formField->get_setting($setting);
}
$data['fields'][] = $object;
```

...or choose our key in advance:

```
$i++;
foreach ($settings as $setting) {
    $data['fields'][$i] = $formField->get_setting($setting);
}
```